# Unverified breakpoints with vscDebugger on VSCode

Tags: r, vscode-debugger, rdebug

I have set up R Debugger on VSCode but it doesn't hit the breakpoints because they're "unverified". I have updated R to version 4.3.1 and reinstalled the extensions and the vscDebugger package, but I can't make it work. I have tried the "Launch R-Workspace" and "Attach to R process", setting breakpoints before launching the debugger and they're shown with red dots, so they're verified, but they become unverified with grey dots as soon as the debugger launches.

I have tried creating a new workspace with one folder and one test R file in it, and I get the same behaviour. What can I do to make it work?

This is the output of R.Version() just in case

```
R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$crt
[1] "ucrt"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "3.1"

$year
[1] "2023"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "16"

$`svn rev`
[1] "84548"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)"

$nickname
[1] "Beagle Scouts"
```